# /assets 404 on javascript_include_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my view:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr" %>
```

Inspect element:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
(ERROR IN RED):GET http://my-server.dev/assets/ 404 (Not Found)
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can use the stylesheet_link_tag without trouble.
Why is the javascript tag getting a 404?

Comment: Well, it works on heroku but not locally..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets are. If in doubt, specify the full path that the browser should look in.

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html